# OK in bash, not OK in sh - convert diff < (ls) <(df)

Tags: bash, sh

In GNU Bash, `diff <(df) <(ls)` is running.
In `sh`, it isn't.
I also tried `[[diff </bin/df <bin/ls]]`, still error:

```
$ [[/usr/bin/diff < (/bin/ls) < (bin/df)]]
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$ bash
```

anyone knows the equivalent of `sh`? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: What's the OS, or GNU/Linux distribution, or..?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent to `<(…)` `>(…)` substitutions – you'll need to manually create named pipes as a replacement:

```
mkfifo /tmp/lspipe
mkfifo /tmp/dfpipe
/bin/ls > /tmp/lspipe &
/bin/df > /tmp/dfpipe &
/usr/bin/diff /tmp/lspipe /tmp/dfpipe
rm /tmp/lspipe /tmp/dfpipe
```

(Also note that in Bash, there is *no* space between the `<` and the `(…)`.)

The `[[…]]` make absolutely no sense in this context. They're not for grouping commands, but for writing conditional expressions (do not confuse them with `( )` or `{ }` which do group commands). It is also a Bash-specific feature, but in places where it's used correctly, it can be replaced with `[ … ]` or with `expr`.